# INVALID_FIELD, Foreign key external ID not found - Inserting Related Records via External Id

Tags: apex, relationships, externalid, insert, dynamic-apex

I am trying to insert related records via an External Id. i am using an approach described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/02/cascade-insert-with-external-id-fields.html) where we create an empty parent object with the same external Id like the "real" parent. It is a self-relationship and i am using dynamic apex to make it usable for multiple objects.

```
Type accountType = Type.forName('Account'); // lets use Account as an example

SObject realParent = (SObject) accountType.newInstance(); // creating the parent
realParent.put('Name', 'myName');
realParent.put('ExtId__c', 'A876');

SObject emptyParent = (SObject) accountType.newInstance(); // creating the reference to the parent
emptyParent.put('ExtId__c', 'A876');

SObject child = (SObject) accountType.newInstance(); // creating the child
child.put('Name','otherName');
child.put('ExtId__c','A123');
child.putSObject('ParentAccount__r', emptyParent); // relating child to Parent

List<SObject> records = new List<SObject> {realParent, child};
insert records;
```

This works fine for other relationships and also if the parent is already existent in the database. However for this self-relationship the insert fails with following message:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: INVALID_FIELD,
>   Foreign key external ID: a876 not found for field ns__ExtId__c in
>   entity Account: [] Class.ns.myClassName.myMethodName: line 27,
>   column 1

Line 27 column 1 refers to the dml insert statement.

Has anyone experienced similar issues or an idea how to solve this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make `upsert` instead of insert

Comment: [Upsert statements are not allowed for generic SObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008y4UIAQ) I am separating existing records from new records and handle them in two dml statements. Relating them in the afore mentioned manner is working fine for Update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) (emphasis mine):

> You can create related records that are up to 10 levels deep. Also, **the related records created in a single call must have different sObject types**. For more information, see [Creating Records for Different Object Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm#MixedSaveSection) in the *SOAP API Developer's Guide*.

Comment: Alright this explains it of course. So then i would have to insert the records separately. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: That's correct. You can't combine calls in this case. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.